# С#. С чего начать?

Tags: c#, книги

Привет! Хочу начать изучать C#. Не подскажете литературу какую-нибудь, сайты? Очень хочется, так как Delphi для моих задач никак не подойдёт, а C# отлично подходит :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Герберт Шилдт - C# 4.0. Полное руководство.

Отличный учебник без всяких излишеств. Далее (говоря наперёд и может быть это послужить как источник вдохновения для изучения C#) могу посоветовать смотреть в сторону XAML и Metro-приложений, т.к релиз Win8 всё ближе и ближе, а там если вы не знаете сотворили свой магазин приложений, а окошками пользуются как я слышал ~90% всех пользователей компьютеров, а это очень много и как вы знаете в магазине можно продавать.

Answer (score 4):

Ну есть начинать изучать C#, было бы хорошо знать C++ хотя бы основы. 
А так Эндрю Троелсен - Язык программирования C# (тут будет год стоять, выбирай на наиболее поздний)
Очень хорошая книга.

Comment: Поддерживаю, а лучше C -> C++ -> C# и/или Java. Сначала времени уйдет больше, но потом, поверьте, будете развиваться семимильными шагами.

Answer (score 2):

Эндрю Стиллмен и Дженнифер Грин "Изучаем C#" Книга из серии HeadFirstLab...меня буквально затянула, до нее языки программирования не знал вообще(сами языки то не проблема была никогда выучить, а вот понять, что-куда и зачем(это я про ООП), до этой книги было сложно).

Сейчас легко усваиваю книги посложнее(Герберд Шильдт), даже взялся за ASP.

Answer (score -2):

Вот почитай http://rghost.ru/37068398, я с него начинал, а про C++ не согласен, я знал только VB и всё и выучил C# на базовом уровне без всяких С++... Ну и конечно же MSDN!!!

Comment: Ну я с тобой не очень согласен, всё же знать что такое указатели,
классы как с ними работать и т.д., мелкие особенности языка надо знать.
С ними учится в разы проще, не отвлекаясь на мелочи. Я не говорю что знать С++ надо полностью, но основы да.

Comment: Я начал с паскаля, там всё расставляешь по полочкам и дальше учить уже всё легче намного.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что C++ не особо необходим. Сам сначала знал Pascal, потом С/С++, а потом уже C#; и считаю, что все до C# было не сильно полезнее, чем пустая трата времени. Надеюсь, из суммы наших мнений можно получить что-то близкое к истине... ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ваши комментарии, буду думать

Comment: Ну паскаль вообще не нужен ни где, в нынешнее время то)

Comment: Из c++ знаю циклы, if'ы, как переменные делать, простейшие операции с переменными. :)

Comment: Ну почитай еще про указатели и классы как создавать.. да думаю и всё. 
Просто всё еще зависит от книги которую будешь читать, будет ли в ней разбираться эти вопросы.
Ибо всё в C#  идет через классы.